# How to verify PKCS7 signature with multiple signers entities in C++

Tags: c++, cryptography, pkcs#7

I check PKCS7 signature with CryptVerifyDetachedMessageSignature and CryptVerifyMessageSignature functions.
Both of them can verify pkcs7 file with certificate which I provided in PCCERT_CONTEXT structure. I got PCCERT_CONTEXT with CertCreateCertificateContext function.

But now I have other task. I have to extract certiticateS from pkcs7 file and verify signatures with all of them.
Can you help me to know how could I do this things:

1. Extract certificates from pkcs7 (more than one);
2. Verify pkcs7 signature with them.

I have to use C++ with CryptoApi for this tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If I take a look at the API it seems you can use the `dwSignerIndex` to verify all the signatures. The the certificate that was used to create the signature is returned in `ppSignerCert`.

The API says the following about `dwSignerIndex`:

> The index of the desired signature. There can be more than one signature. CryptVerifyMessageSignature can be called repeatedly, incrementing dwSignerIndex each time. Set this parameter to zero for the first signer, or if there is only one signer. If the function returns FALSE, and GetLastError returns CRYPT_E_NO_SIGNER, the previous call processed the last signer of the message.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is. But not only. We also have to get conforming Cert Context. For that we can use CryptQueryObject, CryptMsgGetParam, CertFindCertificateInStore. I post some code later.